# Extending a class to an interface in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

The information found under the section *“Interfaces Extending Classes”* of http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html states that

> Interfaces inherit even the private and protected members of a base
>   class.

However, when I tried, TypeScript prompts an error stating that the derived class incorrectly implements the interface – and the *private* and *protected* members of the base class are missing in the derived class.

Following is the code:

```
class View {
  private content: any;
  protected presentation: string;
  public render() {
    console.log("View::render()");
    console.log("content: ", this.content);
    console.log("presentation: ", this.presentation);
  }
  constructor(c: string, p: string) {
    this.content = c;
    this.presentation = p;
  }
}

interface ViewShadow extends View {}

class MobileDisplay implements ViewShadow {
  private content: any;
  protected presentation: string;

  public render() {
    console.log("View::render()");
    console.log("content: ", this.content);
    console.log("presentation: ", this.presentation);
  }
  constructor(c: string, p: string) {
    this.content = c;
    this.presentation = p;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the **exact** error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inherit a class in an interface, the interface will inherit the private members of the class but the problem is that you can't implement the private field, the compiler will accept nothing as an implementation for the `protected`/`private` fields except the original fields. So your implementation would have to inherit `View` to correctly implement the ViewShadow interface:

```
class MobileDisplay  extends View implements ViewShadow {
}
```

Generally thought non public fields should not be part of interfaces meant to be implemented. If you want just the public fields/methods you could use a mapped type:

```
interface ViewShadow extends Pick<View, keyof View> { }

class MobileDisplay implements ViewShadow {
    private content: any;
    protected presentation: string;
    public render() {
        console.log("View::render()");
        console.log("content: ", this.content);
        console.log("presentation: ", this.presentation);
    }
    constructor(c: string, p: string) {
        this.content = c;
        this.presentation = p;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep reading the documentation. Two sentences after the one you quoted, it says:

> This means that when you create an interface that extends a class with private or protected members, **that interface type can only be implemented by that class or a subclass of it.**

(emphasis mine).

So you need

```
class MobileDisplay extends View implements ViewShadow
```